# how to preserve session data on delete on pod restart on k8s cluster on bare metal environment?

Tags: asp.net-core, kubernetes, session, kubernetes-statefulset

My application depends on session. And when the pod is deleted for any reason and recreated the session is gone of-course. Any ideas or workaround on how to keep the session during the recreation process of the pod.

Specs:
App: .Net Core 3.1 Monolithic application deployed on statefulset on K8S environment
K8S env: Bare-Metal with Ubuntu cluster

Comment: Remember that sessions must be saved outside the instance, see the 12 factor app: https://12factor.net/

Comment: @Eslam Ali Has your issue been resolved using the 12 factor app as suggested by Jonas?

Comment: @fariya-rahmat the solution is Distributed session with ASP.NET Core, but I didn't start this task yet.

Comment: @fariya-rahmat if you found a good free tool please share.